# Compiling GREP 2.18 on OS X 10.9.2

Tags: macos, grep

When I attempt to build grep-2.18 on Mac OS X 10.9.2, make returns

```
ld: warning: ignoring file libgrep.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): libgrep.a
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
```

It then lists what must be inside `libgrep.a` that got ignored. Please help, This has baffled me for ages.
Also, I'm the sort of person that is fussy and doesn't like using pre-built binaries, so please do not tell me to use MacPorts, Homebrew, etc...

Answer (score 0):

build grep-2.20 with this configuration

```
 ./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --build=i386-apple-darwin CFLAGS=-m32
```